# Can't overload Delegate for Custom Event?

Tags: c#, winforms

i want to create

```
    public delegate void ValueChangedHandler(int value);
    public delegate void ValueChangedHandler(Object sender, int value);
```

it refuses: how to do so or is it impossible ?

*EDIT: Thanks for the answer, I understand the technical reason, but still what I want to do makes sense from expressivity point of view so I'm upset that .net framework doesn't have a way to do so.*

Comment: A delegate merely stores functions.... kind of like a function pointer, but an easier-to-use concept :)

Comment: A delegate is a type, like a class.  You can't overload types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A delegate is a type. i.e if you are creating a delegate then you are actually making a class which is derived from System.Delegate.

```
public delegate void ValueChangedHandler(int value);
```

So by this you have created a class ValueChangedHandler. So again if you are writing

```
public delegate void ValueChangedHandler(int value, int j);
```

then it is two classes with same name under a single namespace. So the compiler will not allow.

Answer (score 4):

You're confusing delegates and methods... Methods can be overridden, delegates can't.

A delegate is a type, you can declare a variable of type `ValueChangedHandler`:

```
ValueChangedHandler handler;
```

If you could overload delegates, to which overload of `ValueChangedHandler` would this code refer ?

Overloading delegates just wouldn't make sense...

Comment: That's right. It's like creating two classes with the same name in a same namespace. Delegate is a type.

Comment: Technically yes but from User's point of view what I want to do makes sense.

Comment: Perhaps you should describe what you want in more detail... I don't see how having 2 delegate types with same name will help you in any way.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that you can overload delegates, never seen it before.

What I would suggest would be something like this :

```
public delegate void ValueChangedHandler(params object[] list);
```

Hope this helps,

Answer (score 1):

Since ValueChangedHandler is not a method, but a type, you can't overload it - you can instead create a new event handler with different parameters.

The common practice is also to extend paraterers of an event handler:

```
public delegate void EventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e);
```

You can define your custom class extending EventArgs to pass more data.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.delegate.aspx The Delegate class is the base class for delegate types. However, only the system and compilers can derive explicitly from the Delegate class or from the MulticastDelegate class. It is also not permissible to derive a new type from a delegate type. The Delegate class is not considered a delegate type; it is a class used to derive delegate types.